# re.sub with variables, whole string by itself only

Tags: python, regex, substitution

Column 1 in my csv has the target_string (to be replaced) and column 2 is the context (text_column). I can't get it to only remove the string when it is stand alone. I have tried adding \b, but that doesn't work.

Text : `"Foo, FOOBAR FOO FOOBAR FOO FOO FOOBAR."`

```
string_column = col [1]
text_column = col [2]
string_replacement = "BAR"

text_column = re.sub(string_column, string_replacement, text_column, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

What I get is : `"BARBAR BAR BARBAR BAR BAR BARBAR."`

What I need is: `"FOOBAR BAR FOOBAR BAR BAR FOOBAR."`

***EDIT*** I don't think this is a duplicate of the linked question. Those responses wouldn't have helped me, and are far more complicated than the simple solution provided here.

Comment: Like this [`\bFOO\b`](https://regex101.com/r/aM8tfn/1)?

Comment: You haven't shown how your `\b` was added and it doesn't work.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye sorry I didn't want to post the broken code, I just posted the one that I got to work, just not 100%.. I had added \b before and after `string_column` in the `re.sub` and it gave an error

Comment: @Gurman I can't do that because it is not always `Foo`. I am using the variable `string_column` because the target string will change for each run.

Comment: so what you tried, which did not work, was `text_column = re.sub(\bstring_column\b, string_replacement, text_column, flags=re.IGNORECASE)`..?

Comment: @physlexic yes.

Comment: I don't see the "duplication".. same topic, different environment/requirements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You (probably) need `\b` on both sides:

```
import re

string = "Foo, FOOBAR FOO FOOBAR FOO FOO FOOBAR."

your_string_here = "FOO"
string_column = r"\b{}\b".format(your_string_here)
string_replacement = "BAR"

string = re.sub(string_column, 'BAR', string)
print(string)
```

This yields

```
Foo, FOOBAR BAR FOOBAR BAR BAR FOOBAR.
```

Comment: thank you, but I need to keep the variables.. this works, but the target string will not always be 'FOO'.. which is why I defined the variable as `col [1]`

Comment: @chrissmit.yam90: See the updated answer then.

Comment: thank you, this works.. i didn't think to add another processing step, i was tunneled into just editing the `re.sub`